# How to use poll function correctly with socket

Tags: c, sockets, networking

Hi I want to use the poll function to wait the permission to read the stdin and send the result in a socket and after that i want to wait the permission to write this result in the stdout. I tried to use poll as you can see in the code below but it doesn't work correctly when i run the main program with two terminal one as server and the other as client.Nothing appear on my stdout even with a flush and after the timout i get this message
`Did not receive sent data in the last 5 sec.Received only 0 bytes out of 1024`
Could you tell me if I use the function correctly or how should I use it
Thanks

```
void read_write_loop(int sfd){
    int n;
    char buffer_in[1024];



    struct pollfd poll_files_descriptors[2];
    int stdin_to_stdout;

    poll_files_descriptors[0].fd  = STDIN_FILENO;
    poll_files_descriptors[0].events = POLLIN;

    //see if you can wirte to stdout

    poll_files_descriptors[1].fd = STDOUT_FILENO;
    poll_files_descriptors[1].events = POLLOUT;

    stdin_to_stdout = poll(poll_files_descriptors, 2 , 2000 );
    if(stdin_to_stdout == -1){
        perror("poll not working ");
        return;
    }



    while( !feof(stdin)){
        if(poll_files_descriptors[0].revents & POLLIN){
            //readable et il y qqch
            n = fread(&buffer_in,sizeof(buffer_in),1, stdin);
            if(n==0) break;

            int sent_status = send(sfd, buffer_in, n, 0);

            if(sent_status == -1){
                printf("nothing sent");
            }

        }
        if(poll_files_descriptors[1].revents & POLLOUT){
            int receive_status = recv(sfd, buffer_in, n , 0);
            if(receive_status == -1){ // number of bytes
                printf("nothing received");
            }
            fwrite(&buffer_in, sizeof (char), receive_status,stdout );
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 'int sent_status = send(sfd, buffer_in, sizeof(buffer_in), 0);'  why are you sending 'sizeof(buffer_in)' bytes when, two lines up, you know that 'n' bytes have been loaded into the buffer?

Comment: 'it doesn't work correctly'......how so?   How did you test it, and what were the results?

Comment: @MartinJames yeah right just corrected it! I tried with to terminal one run in server state and the other in client state with same ip and port but it doesn't write anything in the stdout when i send a message in stdin even with a fflush

Comment: "Did not receive sent data in the last 5 sec.Received only 0 bytes out of 1024"